# Split string in HTML Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular8

I have `datasource=details` and it has two parameters `nameOfFruits and type`. For `nameOfFruits` I am receiving a string like `"Apple,Banana,Orange,Kiwi,Mango"`. I am trying to display the list in a table as below:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="nameOfFruits">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name of Fruit </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" class="addTag">{{element.nameOfFruits}}
            </td>
 </ng-container>
```

I am trying to apply `addTag` class to each fruit separately but I am not able to split it and apply on each fruit rather it is applying to entire list.

I tried to split the list in TS file before binding with dataSource like:

```
this.details.data = response.Items;
for (let i = 0; i <= this.details.data.length; i++){
this.splittedList[i] = this.details.data[i].nameOfFruits.split(',');
this.finalList.push(this.splittedList[i]);
this.details.data[i]['nameOfFruits'] = this.finalList[i];
}
```

But still I am not able to see a splitted list in UI. Is there a way to use a custom pipe and implement it directly?

Comment: what exactly comes in this.details.data?

Comment: it is an array of objects basically ```[{},{},{}]``` the size is dynamic. Each object as two parameters ```nameOfFruits``` and ```type```

Comment: i am simply binding the ```type``` in one column of the row and want to display all ```nameOfFruits``` in one column but I am applying some css class to separate each fruit. otherwise it looks like a paragraph

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have columns definition list as this:

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
```

displayedColumns should have a list of all columns which you'll define here

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of myColumns" matColumnDef="nameOfFruits{{col}}">
```

So finally your code for additional columns should look like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{col}}" *ngFor="let col of columnList">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fruit {{col}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef class="addTag">whatever</td>
</ng-container>
```

I hope I understand your question and hope this will help ;)
This code has not been tested, so try to find bugs by yourself. The main idea is that all columns have to be defined in separate template.

Comment: ```<ng-container matColumnDef="{{nameOfFruits}}" *ngFor="let nameOfFruits of details">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fruit {{nameOfFruits}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef class="addTag">what do display here/</td>
</ng-container>```

Comment: should this is how my code should look like? Also, how would I be applying the tag. I tried this, it says: ```Could not find column with id "nameOfFruits"```

Comment: can you also add how did you get ```cloumnList```?

Comment: columnList is an array of names of columns you want to display - put it in the component's code.